# Can't emit current serverstate with socket.io during shell exec

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, socket.io

I want to execute a shell build script and emit the current execution state to the angular client. The problem is, that emit is not executed immediately after call. The program waits for completing the whole function and send those emits all together afterwards.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

[...]

app.post('/bootupserver', function(req, res) {
  progress = [];
  io.emit('update', getCurrentServerState());

  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'bootserver.json');
  const file = fs.readFileSync(filePath, { encoding: 'utf-8' });

  progress = Object.values(JSON.parse(file));
  progress.forEach(line => {
      line[0] = 1;
      io.emit('update', getCurrentServerState());
      execSync(line[2]);
      line[0] = 2;
  });
  io.emit('update', getCurrentServerState());

  res.sendStatus(200);
});

[...]
```

To understand the forEach here is my dummy bootserver.json. One array contains three values: state (0=wait, 1=wip, 2=done) , name and command.

```
{
  "0": [2, "0", "sleep 2"],
  "1": [2, "A", "sleep 1"],
  "2": [1, "b", "sleep 0.2"],
  "3": [0, "C", "sleep 1"],
  "4": [0, "d", "sleep 0.2"],
  "5": [0, "E", "sleep 1"],
  "6": [0, "f", "sleep 5"],
  "7": [0, "G", "sleep 2"],
}
```

Here is my angular code to listen for messages:

```
const observable = new Observable<string>((observer: any) => {
  io(url, { secure: true }).on('update', (msg: string) => {
    observer.next(msg);
  });
});
```

I would expect, that there is a mechanism to flush/force the emit to straight update my frontend. Is there some kind of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using synchronous operations and they block the event loop so asynchronous operations (such as networking) may not proceed until the event loop is available.

You can fix it by getting rid of your synchronous operations (rewriting with asynchronous operations) so that the event loop is allowed to operate during your loop.

Here's a way to code with asynchronous I/O and uses `async/await` to more easily make the loop work:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const promisify = require('util').promisify;
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

const execP = promisify(exec);

app.post('/bootupserver', async function(req, res) {
  progress = [];
  io.emit('update', getCurrentServerState());

  try {

      const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'bootserver.json');
      const file = await fsp.readFile(filePath, { encoding: 'utf-8' });

      progress = Object.values(JSON.parse(file));
      for (let line of progress) {
          line[0] = 1;
          io.emit('update', getCurrentServerState());
          await execP(line[2]);
          line[0] = 2;
      }
      io.emit('update', getCurrentServerState());

      res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch(e) {
      res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

> I would expect, that there is a mechanism to flush/force the emit to straight update my frontend. Is there some kind of that?

Not directly.  You'd have to put each iterations of your loop into a `setTimeout()` (and thus couldn't use a regular `for` or `.forEach()` loop) in order to give other things a chance to run before running the next iteration of your loop.  The better option is to just switch to an asynchronous design so everything can cooperatively run together.  This is how node.js is designed to work.

---

In case you're curious, `util.promisify()` treats `exec()` specially so that its callback that looks like `(err, stdio, stderr)` rather than the standard async callback of `(err, value)` will still work properly (it changes the two results internally to `{stdio, stderr}` so it's one value that can come out of the promise).  You're not using those returned values so it doesn't matter here, but if you were they could still work properly.